# Issue with datepicker alignment with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align the input controls and facing issue with the alignment.
Here is the code snippet I tried to create the UI design.I need to create UI with rectangle borders/containers around  each set of input controls and let me know if we can achieve similar with Booststrap. [image].

In the above picture the 'calendar icon' is not moving next to 'Date' textbox and pushing other controls which is causing alignment issue.
I have mock up design as well.

```
    <div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">
  <form>
        <div class="form-row">

            <div class=" form-group date col-md-2 ">
                <label for="DateFrom">Date From</label>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="DateFrom">
                <span class="form-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group date  col-md-2">
                <label for="Dateto">Date To</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dateto">
                <span class="form-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>

            <div class=" form-group col-md-2 ">
                <label for="DD1">Dropdown1</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="DD1">
                    <option selected value=All>All</option>
                    <option value=Val1>Val1</option>
                    <option value=Val2>Val2</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class=" form-group col-md-3 ">
                <label for="DD2">Dropdwon2</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="DD2">
                    <option value=All>All</option>
                    <option value=val1>val1</option>
                    <option value=val2>val2</option>

                </select>
            </div>
            <div class=" form-group col-md-3 ">
                <label for="DD3">Dropdown3</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="disposition">
                    <option value=All>All</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">

            <div class=" form-group col-md-2">
                <label for="Date">Date</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="dateradio" checked>Start Date</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="dateradio">End Date</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label for="dd4">Dropdown4</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="dd4">
                    <option selected value=All>All</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class=" form-group col-md-2 ">
                <label for="DDl5">Dropdowmn5</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="DDl5">
                    <option value=All>All</option>

                </select>
            </div>

            <div class=" form-group col-md-2">
                <label for="Dsply">Display</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Dsply" checked>Val1</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Dsply">Val2</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">

            <div class=" form-group col-md-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" >btn1</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" >btn2</button>
            </div>
            <div class=" form-group col-md-2 ">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" >btn3</button>
            </div>

            <div class=" form-group col-md-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >btn4</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Please find mock up design and expected output
[image]
Could you please let me know how to fix alignment and move 'calendar icon' next/inside-right to date textbox and get the borders around input controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna try to **answer first** about the **'calendar icon'**.
You need to make ***css*** that gonna show icon in **background** and push text I would do it like this:

```css
#icon {
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  background: #f5f5f5 url(http://i.imgur.com/5xD8KRw.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left 10px center;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="icon" value="input">
```

If you need to use **only Bootstrap** then I would suggest to use **`<span>`** with bootstrap class `input-group-addon` and put **`<i>`** **tag** with icon inside it.
For example:

```
<form>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
</form>
```

So the output should be something like this:

[image: Bootstrap Input]

And for this you need to find the right ***size of column in Bootstrap*** so basically your ***`col-md-2`*** if you **change** the number to ***`4,3,5,8 (col-md-4)`*** it's gonna make **different size** of column in row so you can play with it.

Other changes:
 - for ***new line*** you can use **HTML** tag `<br />`
 - and to align radio buttons use class `text-left`

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">
  <form>
        <div class="form-row">

            <div class=" form-group date col-md-3 ">
                <label for="DateFrom">Date From</label>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="DateFrom">
                <span class="form-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group date  col-md-3">
                <label for="Dateto">Date To</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dateto">
                <span class="form-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>

            <div class=" form-group col-md-2 ">
                <label for="DD1">Dropdown1</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="DD1">
                    <option selected value=All>All</option>
                    <option value=Val1>Val1</option>
                    <option value=Val2>Val2</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class=" form-group col-md-2 ">
                <label for="DD2">Dropdwon2</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="DD2">
                    <option value=All>All</option>
                    <option value=val1>val1</option>
                    <option value=val2>val2</option>

                </select>
            </div>
            <div class=" form-group col-md-2 ">
                <label for="DD3">Dropdown3</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="disposition">
                    <option value=All>All</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">

            <div class=" form-group col-md-4 text-left">
                <label for="Date">Date</label>
                <br />
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="dateradio" checked>Start Date</label>

                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="dateradio">End Date</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label for="dd4">Dropdown4</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="dd4">
                    <option selected value=All>All</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class=" form-group col-md-3 ">
                <label for="DDl5">Dropdowmn5</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="DDl5">
                    <option value=All>All</option>

                </select>
            </div>

            <div class=" form-group col-md-2 text-left">
                <label for="Dsply">Display</label>
                <br />
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Dsply" checked>Val1</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Dsply">Val2</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">

            <div class=" form-group col-md-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" >btn1</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" >btn2</button>
            </div>
            <div class=" form-group col-md-2 ">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" >btn3</button>
            </div>

            <div class=" form-group col-md-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >btn4</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Slaby - Thanks for css class used for calendar icon.I would prefer to use bootstrap class to set the icon next to textbox. I tried playing with  mod 4,5,6 but alignment is more and pushing text to next line might be calendar icon is coming to next line.Could you please let me know using bootstrap css to set calendar icon next to textbox.

Comment: I edited my previous answer how to do it only with Bootstrap. Hope it's gonna help.

Comment: Slabu-Thanks.It worked able to see icon next to textbox and other elements aligned properly except buttons.Is it possible to have rectangles continers around ech group as shown in UI

Comment: You have rectangle containers...or do you mean that you want to see border?

Comment: Sorry for delay in response.I am looking for border around each group of input elements

Comment: You can check out this [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/)  . Other way it just means you have to use class **border**.